# Do any molecules escape from the pan's surface when you heat it up?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, phase-transition

If the bonds strength between molecules in a solid depends on the position of the particles' electrons in some instant, wouldn't that mean that some of the bonds have minimum strength according to the electron arrangement in that particular time?

If so, when the thermal energy reaches the most weakly bonded molecules, could by any chance any of them brake free (while the bulk of the material remains in solid state)?

---

thinking that of a health point of view, maybe some metallic molecules reach our food while cooking

Comment: some molecules most definitely reach our food. The real question is the amount of molecules, and whether it represents a non-negligible intake of harmful substances.

Comment: Assuming we have something like a cast iron skillet (so nothing coated, just "pure" iron), I think we can use the approximation that $1 / k_B \simeq 11604 \mathrm{K / eV} $, so breaking bonds just using temperature seems out of the question, although there might be other processes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronvolt#Temperature